# Show that $\mathbb Z_{p\mathbb Z}$ is a subring of $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have to show that $\mathbb Z_{p\mathbb Z} = \{\frac{a}{b} \ |\ a,b \in \mathbb Z, b \notin p \mathbb Z  \}$ is a subring of $\mathbb Q$.

What I know:

- $\mathbb Z_{p\mathbb Z}$ is a subring of $\mathbb Q$ if:

1. $\mathbb Z_{p\mathbb Z} \subseteq \Bbb Q$
2. $\mathbb Z_{p\mathbb Z}$ is a ring, so $(\mathbb Z_{p\mathbb Z}, +)$ is a subgroup and $(\mathbb Z_{p\mathbb Z}, \cdot)$ is a monoid

- $p \Bbb Z = \{p \cdot z \ |\ p$ is some prime, $z \in \Bbb Z \}$ a subgroup of $\Bbb Z$

First I wan't to show the closure regarding $(\mathbb Z_{p\mathbb Z}, +)$.

Let $x, y \in \Bbb Z_{p\mathbb Z}$ such that $x = \frac{a}{b}$ and $y = \frac{c}{d}$. Then $x + y = \frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} = \frac{ad + bc}{bd}$. Now I have to show that this is also in $\Bbb Z_{p\mathbb Z}$.

My reasoning: because $b,d \in \Bbb Z$ and $b,d \notin p\Bbb Z$, I concluded that they have to be of the form: $b = kz + r$ and $d = k'z' + r'$, where $k, k' \in \Bbb N$, $z \in \Bbb Z_{p\mathbb Z}$ and $0 \le r \lt k$, $0 \le r' \lt k'$. So, $b$ and $d$ cannot be divided by any $z \in p\Bbb Z$ without a remainder.

Then $b \cdot d = (kz + r) \cdot (k'z' + r') = (k k' z'+ kr')z + (k'z' + r')r = ez + r''$, so $b \cdot d \notin p\Bbb Z$.

Is my reasoning regarding $b,d$ correct? If not, a little help would be appreciated

Comment: Isn't it less of a mess to note that if $p$ does not divide $b$ nor $d$, then it does not divide $bd$, since a prime divides a product if and only if it divides one of the factors? Note that your argument is not sufficient: you never tell us what  $k$ and $k'$ are (the relevant division is division by $p$, not by some random $k$), and you never say why $r''$ cannot be a multiple of $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning for $bd$ is neither complete nor correct.

You seem to be dividing by $k$ and $k'$ (note that conditions you are putting on the remainder); but you never tell us what $k$ and $k'$ are. That makes that division useless to detect whether something is a multiple of $p$.

Instead, you should be dividing by $p$, and writing $b=kp+r$ with $0\lt r\lt p$ (note the strict inequality, since you are assuming that $b$ is *not* a multiple of $p$), and $d=k'p+r'$, with $0\lt r'\lt p$. Then your calculations will end up with $bd = (kk'p + kr'+k'r)p + rr'$, and now you must show that $rr'$ is not a multiple of $p$... which just reduces to the original issue: showing that the product of two numbers, neither of which is a multiple of $p$, is also not a multiple of $p$.

Note that this claim is false when $p$ is not a prime (for example, $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{5}{6}$, so if you were trying to argue that if neither $b$ nor $d$ are multiples of $6$ then $bd$ is not multiple of $6$, the argument woudl fail). So you must *somehow* use the fact that $p$ is a prime number, which is something you have failed to do.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The fact about $p$ not dividing $b$ nor $d$ and therefore not dividing $bd$ didn't come to my mind. And I see now what you mean about $k, k^{'}$ and $r^{'}$. Thank You very much for making it clear!